# Compact notation for multiple sums

Tags: summation, notation, index-notation

Consider a multiple series of the form:
$$
\sum_{k_1=0}^\infty\cdots\sum_{k_n=0}^\infty f(k_1,\dots,k_n).
$$
I have a more complicated multiple series where the indicies are $k_{jn}$ with $j=1,\dots,J$ and $n=1,\dots,n_j$ (note that $n_j$ changes with $j$).  How can I compactly represent such a series?

Perhaps:
$$
\sum_{\mathbf k=0}^\infty f(\mathbf k),
$$
where $\mathbf k=(k_{1,1},\dots,k_{1,n_1},\dots,k_{J,1},\dots,k_{J,n_J})$?  I feel like this too is very clunky.  Is there a generally accepted notation for writing such series?

Comment: @JulesBesson No, I have a total of $\sum_{j=1}^Jn_j$ variates.

Comment: Can you have twice the same tuple in your sum?

Comment: Are you assuming the sum is absolutely summable, or something similar?  If not, there may be no way to rewrite your original series (the notation itself begs some Fubini-type result)

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes, you can assume absolute convergence. $f(\cdot)$ is positive for all indices and converges.

Comment: I wouldn't have any problem with $\displaystyle \sum_{\mathbf{k} \geq \mathbf{0}} f(\mathbf{k})$ where $\mathbf{k}$ is as you define.  Is it your definition of $\mathbf{k}$ that you feel is clunky?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multi-index, (it can be shaped in many different ways in order to have more various sums)

$$\sum_{\alpha \in A} f(\alpha)$$
with $A \subset \mathbb{N}^{(\mathbb{N})}$ (finished support sequences or "almost null sequences") describing your stuff (it is ok since it is countable). But maybe this is not what you want?

I would "put" $k_1,\dots,k_{n_j}$ in $A$ as the sequence $(k_1,\dots,k_{n_j}, 0, \dots , 0, \dots)$
However, if you want to be able to have any integer (including $0$), we could define $Z = \mathbb{Z} \sqcup \{\ast\}$ where $\ast$ will replace your zero, take $A \subset Z^{(\mathbb{N})}$ is given by the sequence where for some $N$ you have $u_k = \ast$ for $k > N$. Then $(k_1,\dots,k_{n_j})$ would be encoded as $(k_1,\dots,k_{n_j}, \ast, \dots , \ast, \dots)$

The only thing you need to have is the summability of your family $f(\alpha)_\alpha$.

I have another Idea with a double sum:
$$\sum_{i = 1}^J \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}^{n_j}} f_i(k)$$

but the problem here is that $f_i$ lives in a different space each time. You could consider the filtered set:
$$N_\infty = \bigsqcup_{i=0}^\infty \mathbb{N}^i$$
which is countable and define $f$ on $A \subset N_\infty$ then you just have:
$$\sum_{\alpha \in A} f(\alpha) $$

Anyway **be careful with the definition of $f$**

Comment: This is close (+1).  Maybe $\sum_{\mathbf k\in\mathcal K}f(\mathbf k)$ where $\mathbf k=(k_{jn})$ for $n\in(1,\dots ,n_j)$ and $j\in(1,\dots,J)$ and $\mathcal K=\Bbb N^{\sum_{j=1}^Jn_j}$?  The hard part seems to be the notation to describe $\alpha$ and $A$ in your answer.

Comment: Ok so $\sum n_j$ is finite

Comment: My example is more "polyvalent" but for your case you might be able to simplify it in another way (I thought the $n_j$ would just be finite for each $j$) I can edit for your example to add the description of $A$.